# How to access a class object when declared in an if statement? (in c++)

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
if (action == "create") {
gymMembership object;
object.name = nameInput;
object.num = numInput;
object.month = 0;
object.print();}

if (action == "extend") {
object.month += monthInput;
object.print();}
```

but on the line  `object.month += monthInput;`

I get this error: `error: 'object' was not declared in this scope`

Note that all this is in a while loop, don't know if it makes any difference

Comment: The object will have to have [its scope widened](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) so that [its lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) extends beyond the if statement's body.

Comment: The solution depends on higher level behavior expected of your program. Please [edit] your post and more context and add more code, preferably a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use it in both `if` statements, you will need to declare it outside of both of them:

```
gymMembership object;
if (action == "create") {
    object.name = nameInput;
    object.num = numInput;
    object.month = 0;
    object.print();
}

if (action == "extend") {
    object.month += monthInput;
    object.print();}
```

Otherwise, it will go out of scope the second it hits the first `}`.

> I have tried that, but then object will lose its values for name and num, and will only have the value for month

So what you want to probably do is something like this:

```
gymMembership object;
if (action == "create") {
    object.name = nameInput;
    object.num = numInput;
    object.month = 0;
    object.print();
}

if (action == "extend") {
    object.name = nameInput;
    object.num = numInput;
    object.month += monthInput;
    object.print();
}
```

Though, now I'm starting to wonder if there's a larger problem in your creation strategy. Perhaps we need a bigger example of what you're trying to accomplish. But I digress...

---

Edit: looking at [your code](http://txt.do/1o07s) (which you posted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967222/how-to-access-a-class-object-when-declared-in-an-if-statement-in-c/58967308?noredirect=1#comment104189451_58967308)), what you're actually doing is more like this:

```
while (true) {
    gymMembership object;
    if (action == "create") {
        object.name = nameInput;
        object.num = numInput;
        object.month = 0;
        object.print();
    }

    if (action == "extend") {
        object.month += monthInput;
        object.print();
    }

}
```

What you seem to want to do is actually put it outside the while loop:

```
gymMembership object;
while (true) {
    if (action == "create") {
        object.name = nameInput;
        object.num = numInput;
        object.month = 0;
        object.print();
    }

    if (action == "extend") {
        object.month += monthInput;
        object.print();
    }

}
```

Otherwise, the `object` will go out of scope when the loop iterates and loose all information stored in it. This way, the object will remain in scope and keep the information from the previous iteration.

Comment: I have tried that, but then object will lose its values for name and num, and will only have the value for month.

Comment: It won't lose them as much as you don't sever set them in the first place. I highly doubt that `action` can equal "create" and "extend" at the same time (in other words, code you haven't shown us doesn't change the value of `action` before it gets to the second `if`), so assuming that I'm going to suggest setting them inside the second `if`.

Comment: What you are assuming is correct, action can be either one of "create" and "extend" through each cycle of the while loop. My code behaves as if I'm creating a new object in the 2nd for loop and only has the value for months. If you care at all, you can find the full code [here](http://txt.do/1o07s). It is not fully done, but at this point it should work for only one customer (or object).

Comment: See edit. I should also reiterate that now i'm not sure this is a good answer, because now I don't know what you're trying to accomplish. Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58967222/edit) and explain what it is you're trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Wait, looked at your code. Put `gymMembership haha;` outside your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `object` is at block scope in the first `if` block.  You need to widen scope.  You can widen scope in a few ways.  You can declare at a block that encloses both if blocks.  You can declare at function scope. You can declare at at module scope.  All of those options will make your variable available in your second `if` block.